# How to list items from another resource in Show layout

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a resource called `main` and it has a field that has IDs of an another resource `branch` in a comma-separated list. I want to list those items in a List-based view, so I can reuse some components from other parts of the code that are RA-oriented.

I came to know about some components like `ReferenceField`, but they can't handle the type of field (comma-separated) that I am using.

Is there a way this can be done in RA?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we recently introduced the `useList` hook for this purpose.

You'll have to first parse your ids list into an array and pass this array to the `useGetMany` hook.

You may then pass the data you get to the `useList` hook which gives a `ListContext` for your data.

Finally you can use the `ListContextProvider` and pass it the context you got in the previous step and use the `Datagrid` component as you usually would.